# Log in facebook android ERROR

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to write an application that can log in to facebook. I use the facebook sdk so I import the classes that are in the facebook sdk.

I go Project-->Proprietes--->Android--->Library  add Facebook SDK but i obtain the follow error ( For all project i have just changed Java compiler propriety at 1.6):

```
0:37 - BooleanOGSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - SessionLoginSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - SwitchUserSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - Hackbook] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - Scrumptious] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - FriendPickerSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - ProfilePictureSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - GraphApiSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - PlacePickerSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:37 - HelloFacebookSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - BooleanOGSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - FacebookSDK] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - FriendPickerSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - GraphApiSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - Hackbook] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - HelloFacebookSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - PlacePickerSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - ProfilePictureSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - Scrumptious] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - SessionLoginSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:10:38 - SwitchUserSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:11:04 - BooleanOGSample] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:11:04 - FacebookSDK] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] Versions found are:
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] Path: C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\Android\Progetti Android\FacebookProvaSd\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd]     Length: 393154
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd]     SHA-1: 307c1cc532eabbf1d135b43e5c983c9da700449d
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] Path: C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\Android\documentazione\Facebook\AltraSDK\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd]     Length: 349252
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd]     SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-04-18 22:15:29 - FacebookProvaSd] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Did you read the errors and do what they said?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I see here:

1. Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
2. Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list

The first problem should easily be solved by simply following the directions. The second problem can also be easily resolved. Simply make sure both the Facebook project and your own Android project both use the same version of the compatibility library. The easiest way is to update both to the latest.